# Does using innerHTML prevent clientside javascript from applying on new html?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, innerhtml, ecmascript-5

I am using .innerhtml to take information from a form, and re-display a list(of dynamic data that displays in the form of a credit card. See following link for example. https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/YONMEa)  to the DOM. However, when I display that information back to the DOM, my client side Javascript does not seem to apply towards the new elements by re-reading their id's and class's.

Snippit of relevant code

```
var renderElement = document.querySelector(".cardbox");
const html = '<div class="card-container preload" id="target" >'+
       '<div class="creditcardrender">'+
       '                            <div class="front">'+
       '                                <div id="ccsingle"></div>'+ ... etc

renderElement.innerHTML += html;
```

Is this a property of HTML/Javascript that is unavoidable or is there a work-around this issue?

thanks.

Comment: Replacing innerHTML is like erasing a whiteboard and redrawing everything. So any events you bind removes them.

Comment: Yes, you have to rebind every events after change innerHTML. But how can I duplicate errors you mentioned? Nice design, though :) Or is this another clever trick to get traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly,

Using `renderElement.innerHTML += html;` is equivalent to `renderElement.innerHTML = renderElement.innerHTML + html;`, which means its value is a new string resulted from the concatenation of the two strings. So, the existing HTML element will be refactored as if you're assigning it from scratch.

To add the HTML code you're hoping to be present, you can use `insertAdjacentHTML()` function to add the HTML code to the element without reforming the existing code.

```js
renderElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
```